# How to remove first and last charcter if character is ',' of name in Sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I combine two column value with ',' using below query.

```
SELECT     
RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(
IsNull(tbl1 .Reason,'') + ',' + IsNull(tbl2.OtherReason,''),',' ,'')))
FROM tbl1 
    LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON tbl2.OtherReasonId = tbl1.ReasonId
```

Now issue is that it remove all ',' using above query and I want to just remove last and first ','.

I have combine two column. Now 
if tbl1 .Reason is null then it display output as " ,tbl2.OtherReason " and if tbl2.OtherReason is null the output is "tbl1 .Reason,"

Before above query, I also try with below query:

```
SELECT 
IsNull(tbl1.Reason,'') + ',' + IsNull(tbl2.OtherReason,'')
FROM tbl1
    LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON tbl2.OtherReasonId = tbl1.ReasonId
```

Thanks,
HItesh

Comment: Are you saying that `tbl1.Reason` may start with a comma and you want to remove it?

Comment: Why don't you just replace `,` with ` ` in first and second column separately and then `CONCAT` them with `,` ? As of SQL Server 2008 `CONCAT` function doesn't exist but you can append strings like `Reason + "," + Reason2`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a case in the middle to check if the values are null or not.

```
declare @a nvarchar(5)
        ,@b nvarchar(5)
set @a = 'abc'
set @b = null--'123'
select  isnull(@a, '') + case when @a is not null and @b is not null then ',' else '' end + isnull(@b, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN tbl1.Reason IS NULL
    THEN 
        CASE
            WHEN tbl2.Reason IS NULL
            THEN ''
            ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(tb2.Reason))
        END
    ELSE tbl1.Reason +
        CASE
            WHEN tbl2.Reason IS NULL
            THEN ''
            ELSE ',' + LTRIM(RTRIM(tb2.Reason))
        END
END
FROM tbl1 
LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON tbl2.OtherReasonId = tbl1.ReasonId
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate a comma to the first value in case that second value is not null :

```
SELECT     
       IsNull(tbl1.Reason + case when tbl2.OtherReason is null then '' else ',' end, '')  +
       IsNull(tbl2.OtherReason,'')
FROM tbl1 
    LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON tbl2.OtherReasonId = tbl1.ReasonId
```